# Show/Hide Div Depending On asp:RadioButton Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an `asp.net webform` application and on one page I have a question with 2 radio buttons and I want an `asp:textbox` to be displayed when one of the options is selected but I cant figure out how to do it using `JQuery`

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label ID="Step03PgSelectionLabel" class="col-sm-4 control-label" runat="server" Text="How many pages would you like us to look at *" style="padding-top: 0px"></asp:Label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <asp:Label runat="server" class="radio-inline" style="padding-top: 0px">
            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="Step03AllPgsRadioButton" value="All" GroupName="Step03PgSelection"/>All
        </asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" class="radio-inline" style="padding-top: 0px">
            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="Step03SelectionPgsRadioButton" name="selection" value="Selection" GroupName="Step03PgSelection"/>Selection
        </asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
        <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomStep03PgSelection" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please select if you would like us to look at all you pages or specific pages." ClientValidationFunction="Step03PgSelection_ClientValidate" OnServerValidate="Step03PgSelection_ServerValidate" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="hiddenSpecificPages">
    <asp:Label ID="Step03SpecificPagesLabel" class="col-sm-4 control-label" runat="server" Text="Please specify all specific page URL's *" AssociatedControlID="Step03SpecificPagesField"></asp:Label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <asp:TextBox ID="Step03SpecificPagesField" runat="server" class="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ID="reqStep03SpecificErrorMessage" SetFocusOnError="true" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="Step03SpecificPagesField" ErrorMessage="Please list all the page URL's you would like us to look at." />
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following `JQuery` but I cant get it working

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name='selection']").click(function () {
        if ($("#MainContent_Step03SelectionPgsRadioButton").is(":checked")) {
            $("#hiddenSpecificPages").show();
        } else {
            $("#hiddenSpecificPages").hide();
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function ()
{
     if ($('#MainContent_Step03SelectionPgsRadioButton').checked = true)
     {
          $('hiddenSpecificPages').show();
     }
     else
     {
          $('hiddenSpecificPages').hide();
     }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#MainContent_Step03SelectionPgsRadioButton').change(function () {
        $('hiddenSpecificPages').show();
    });
});

$(function ()
{
     if ($("#MainContent_Step03SelectionPgsRadioButton").val() == "Selection")
     {
          $("#hiddenSpecificPages").show();
     }
     else
     {
          $("#hiddenSpecificPages").hide();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `hidden` to the top level `div` and amended my name in the following `JQuery`

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" id="hiddenSpecificPages" hidden>
    <asp:Label ID="Step03SpecificPagesLabel" class="col-sm-4 control-label" runat="server" Text="Please specify all specific page URL's *" AssociatedControlID="Step03SpecificPagesField"></asp:Label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <asp:TextBox ID="Step03SpecificPagesField" runat="server" class="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ID="reqStep03SpecificErrorMessage" SetFocusOnError="true" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="Step03SpecificPagesField" ErrorMessage="Please list all the page URL's you would like us to look at." />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name='ctl00$MainContent$Step03PgSelection']").click(function () {
        if ($("#MainContent_Step03SelectionPgsRadioButton").is(":checked")) {
            $("#hiddenSpecificPages").show();
        } else {
            $("#hiddenSpecificPages").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ClientIDMode="Static" for your RadioButton to make sure the ID doesn't change.